# Що таке "кутня" з виразу "сміятися на кутні"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Натрапив на фразеологізм "[Сміятися на кутні](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96)", що означає "плакати".

Але не знаю значення слова "кутня", пошуки в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/kutnja) нічого не дали. Що таке "кутня" і чому якщо я "сміятимуся на кутні", то насправді я плакатиму?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У СУМі є потрібна вам стаття КУ́ТНІЙ: маються на увазі "[кутні](http://sum.in.ua/s/kutnij) зуби":

> **Кутні зуби** — задні п'ять зубів з кожного боку обох щелеп. Повернув Нечипір язиком у роті... аж так і є: намацав піввареника, що застряло у кутніх зубах (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 109); На кутніх зубах спробував [Дорохтей] золото (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 50).

У тій же самій статті:

> **Сміятися (засміятися, реготатися, зареготатися) на кутні [зуби]** — плакати. — Ми то тепер регочемо, а чи не доведеться нам на кутні зареготатись, як німець справді машиною весь хліб підніме? — спитав хтось (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 243); — Ще й сміється, дурне! Щоб ти на кутні сміялося!.. (Олександр Ковінька, Кутя.., 1960, 86).

Тобто "сміятися на кутні зуби" - так сильно сміятися що навіть видно задні зуби. Чому це означає "плакати" - можливо це сарказм, принаймні у наведених прикладах є протиставлення "зараз смієшся/сміємося, а потім будемо ще сильніше "сміятися" (тобто плакати)".

Або цей "зворотній смисл" може бути спостереженням що сильний сміх і плач схожі у своїх проявах. У дитячій книзі "[Тім Талер або проданий сміх](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/James_Kruss/Tim_Taler_abo_Prodanyi_smikh.htm)" головний герой продає свій сміх і більше не може сміятися. Але щоб показати ніби він сміється на комедійній виставі, він плакав, бо сильний сміх схожий на сильний плач:

> В ту хвилину Тім уперше помітив, як схоже виявляються в людини сміх і плач. І він зробив страшну річ: закрив обличчя долонями, нахиливсь уперед і вдав, ніби сміється. А насправді Тім плакав. Крізь сльози він мурмотів: «Сестричко-королівно, ну навіщо ти засміялася? Навіщо?!»

А ось епізод де сміх повертається до героя:

> Колись давно, в ляльковому театрі, йому впало в очі. що сміх і плач бувають зовні дуже схожі. А тепер він дізнався, що сміх і плач часом дуже подібні не тільки зовні - їх іноді й розрізнити важко. Тім сміявся й плакав воднораз. Він здригався, ніби хлипаючи. і з очей йому текли сльози, а руки безвладно обвисли. Він забув геть про все довкола, бо неначе вдруге народжувався на світ.

Щодо фразеологічних прикладів протилежного значення щодо буквального маю приклад побажання "скатертиною дорога", яке колись було побажанням подорожі без пригод, але потім стало означати "ми за вами не будемо сумувати, раді що ви нарешті від нас їдете":

> [Скатертю дорога](http://sum.in.ua/s/dorogha) — уживається при потребі показати, висловити тому, хто йде, їде і т. ін., що за ним не дуже жалкують і без нього обійдуться. — Петруся нашого спитати, — хитнув [Артем] головою на перегородку, — і той знає, що до чого. А він... — Скатертю дорога! — каже. Ви бачили! (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 447);

Comment: Замість _скатертю дорога_ красше уживати _баба з воза_ чи _кобилї легше_.

Answer (score 2):

В доповнення до відповіді Artemix додам, що це може означати плакати, через те, що часто, коли люди плачуть, у них видні кутні зуби. Ось усміхайлик зі скайпівського набору для позначення стурбованості:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

РЕД: Випадково натрапив на таке пояснення у статті [15 влучних українських фразеологізмів на всі випадки життя](https://gazeta.ua/articles/chistota-movlennya/_15-vluchnih-ukrayinskih-frazeologizmiv-na-vsi-vipadki-zhittya/793874) на gazeta.ua:

> Сміятися на кутні – означає геть протилежне – плакати. Самі
>   поміркуйте: зазвичай, людина сміється, коли їй радісно. Та щоб стало
>   видно кутні зуби, усмішка має бути дуже натягнутою. Так буває, коли
>   сміються з примусу, під тиском або плачуть.